# Cloudflare making Site B redirect to Site A

Tags: cloudflare

Currently I host 2 websites through cloudflare.

I bought the domain for the 2nd website tonight and upon setting it up I of course changed the nameservers to cloudflare's. But for some reason that I cannot understand, whenever I access the 2nd website via the domain name it redirects me to my 1st domain on cloudflare.

I can access the 2nd website fine via my external IP instead of the domain name.

It's also worth mentioning that I have set a custom port (2059) for my 2nd website as I host both sites on my home server.

Comment: What are your DNS settings?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I've attached an album of my 2 sites DNS settings on cloudflare. http://imgur.com/a/Lu0J2

Answer (score 1):

Since you have both sites pointed to the same IP, you should look for redirects on your server. htaccess and web.config files should be checked first (https checkers, domain name consolidation, etc).
Also look for domain aliases set up on those sites.
Lastly you should check to see if CF is automatically redirecting traffic based on Page Rules or forcing https.